# Why this loop for finding the prime no is not executing the way expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, while-loop, break

```
def prime_no():
number = int(input("Enter your number for which you wanna generate prime factors: "))
prime = [2,3]
numb = [*range(4, number + 1)]
for x in numb:
    while x > number:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            continue                                                                              
        if x % numb == 0 and x != numb:
            continue
        else:
            prime.append(x)

print(prime)
```

Second is something different in while loop because stack was recognizing it as error.
The output remains the same [2,3]. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: second is elif so dont worry

Comment: functions must also be indented like loops

Comment: Your code is also assuming that every number will have 2 and 3 as its factors, which is not true

Comment: A function which takes an integer input should be *passed* its input rather than relying on the `input()` function. Similarly it should `return` rather than `print` its output. If this is homework (as seems likely) then your instructor is likely to take points away for that (unless your instructor is actively teaching bad habits).

Comment: Your `x` will never be greater than `number` because the list `numb` stops at `number`

Comment: @expressjs123 yes but when i am inputting number + 2 then it is becoming an infinite loop

Comment: And that's because in your while loop you never increment `x`

Comment: oh yes i didnt concentrated on that thanks also what else should i change to make it work?

Comment: @expressjs123 please reply if any

Comment: can you edit so i can see what you tried to change????

Comment: You are contradicting yourself when you complain that the output is `[2,3]` but then says that it raises an error. If the loop raises an error then you never get to the print statement. Which is it?

Comment: `def prime_no():
    number = int(input("Enter your number for which you wanna generate prime factors: "))
    prime = [2,3]
    numb = [*range(4, number + 2)]
    numb2 = [*range(3, number)]
    for x in numb:
        for y in numb2:
            while x > number:
                if x % 2 == 0:
                    continue
                elif x % y == 0:
                    continue
                else:
                    prime.append(x)
                x+=1
    
    print(prime)`

Comment: still infinite :( @expressjs123

Answer (score 0):

`numb` is a list and the modulo operator doesn't work with a list. You're also not indenting properly. As well, `x` is a number and you're checking if it doesn't equal the list `numb` which it will never equal. Hence it's always continuing .

Comment: for indentation i have tried to remove error on stack... and yes x is not equal to list got it, but x can be taken as a number and then i am using modulo operator right?

Comment: I think you misunderstand - you can't find the remainder of dividing an `int` by a `list` it doesn't make sense so python is raising an error